# Can't see anything in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I feel a bit stupid asking this question but when i open a project in android studio, literally nothing shows up on my screen apart from the toolbar. I've had a mess around with the view settings since this occurred but i haven't found anything to help me. Below is a screenshot of my desktop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance.

https://gyazo.com/5549ed669e639906cab1ffd43b1ede32

EDIT*******

Ok so i have reinstalled and got the following error.

https://gyazo.com/48adb068f1b40f19f2cb0effdcc72bb5

Comment: Does reinstalling help?

Answer (score 0):

[image: here]

Click `View` tab and tick the following as in the picture. Let me know if it fails

Comment: how will he go there, if no menu bar and actions are not showing.

Comment: goto `File` ->`settings` -> `Appearance and behavior` ->`Appearance` , select a theme like `Darcula` or any

Comment: If it doen't work try this go to `window` ->`Active tool window`->`Hide all windows` is ticked. if it ticked, untick it

Comment: Tried both of these, still nothing!

Comment: is `hide all window` is ticked or not

Comment: so you have reinstalled, try to create a new project and see if the same error occurs

Comment: what happened did you got it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Go to view -> Tool windows -> Project [image: Please Try this]

Comment: I get no response when either clicking the drop down menu or pressing the cmd + 1 keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Dirty If you are using Windows Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 and delete .AndroidStudio will reset your studio settings. make this file is hidden.

Comment: Mac OSx El Capitan

Comment: @Dirty Than try to find this file in mac and delete it

Comment: @Dirty Please remove ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta  
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta  
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta

Comment: @Dirty Try this rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*

Comment: https://gyazo.com/48adb068f1b40f19f2cb0effdcc72bb5  Getting this error now. Cant seem to find much about it online